# How to set maximum of two numericupdown control

Tags: vb.net

I was making a cinema booking software where after I choose the seats, it stores the number of seats I selected in an integer counter.

I have two NumericUpDown controls: nudAdult & nudKids

My problem is I have to make sure the maximum value of both NumericUpDown controls can't exceed the seatNum counter.

For eg: If the number of seats I chose is 3, both values of nudAdult & nudKids cannot exceed 3 when added together. So nudAdult can be 2 and nudKids can be 1 and I can't increase anymore than that.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me or give me some pointers to solve this problem.

Thank you for any help.

**Edit:** This might have been a wrong approach but it worked to an extend

```
Private Sub nudAdult_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nudAdult.ValueChanged
    totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(nudAdult.Value) + Convert.ToInt32(nudKids.Value)
    Call CheckIfExceed(nudAdult)
End Sub

Private Sub nudKids_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nudKids.ValueChanged
    totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(nudAdult.Value) + Convert.ToInt32(nudKids.Value)
    Call CheckIfExceed(nudKids)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckIfExceed(c As NumericUpDown)
    Dim left As Integer

    If totalCount <= seatCounter Then
        left = seatCounter - totalCount
        c.Maximum = totalCount + left
    Else
        c.Maximum = c.Value - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Think about the problem before thinking about code.  If this was a physical problem rather than a coding problem, how would you do it?  If you don't know that already then you shouldn't even be thinking about writing code.  Don't consider writing code until you know what the code has to do.  That doesn't just mean the end result but every step to get to the end result.

Comment: There is a `maximum` property of the `NumericUpDown` control. See [NumericUpDown.Maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.maximum?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to check anything.  As I said, think about a physical problem.  Let's say that you have 10 balls and two bags and you can put the balls into the bags.  The maximum number of balls you can put in either bag is obviously the number of balls in that bag plus the number of balls not yet in either bag.  That means that, when you start and both bags are empty, then maximum for each bag is the total number of balls.  BOOM!  You now know that you need to set the `Maximum` of each `NumericUpDown` to the total number of seats at the start.

Now, when you place a ball in a bag, the maximum number of balls that can be placed in the other bag obviously decrements by one.  BOOM!  You now know that when the `Value` of one of your `NumericUpDown` controls changes, you need to change the `Maximum` of the other the same amount in the opposite direction.

Look at that!  Problem solved with less than a minute considering an analogous physical problem.

```
Private total As Integer 'Set total here.

Private Sub Start()
    NumericUpDown1.Maximum = total
    NumericUpDown2.Maximum = total
End Sub

Private Sub NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged
    NumericUpDown2.Maximum = total - NumericUpDown1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub NumericUpDown2_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown2.ValueChanged
    NumericUpDown1.Maximum = total - NumericUpDown2.Value
End Sub
```